# how can I highlight the element in which I'm looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, debugging

I been learning to code by my own and my knowledge with Javascript is pretty basic... I'm facing a problem whilst I try to cycle through an list, I want to wrap the element whose index matches the one within the list and get rid of the others.....of course isn't doing what i want, this is what I have:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <ul id='list'>
        <span id='next'>Next</span>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Eagle</li>
        <li>Fox</li>
        <li>Mouse</li>
        <span id='prev'>Prev</span>

        <div id='ci'></div>
    </ul>
```

```
var current_index = 0;
var uli = $("#list li");


function cycle(){
    var start = uli.eq(current_index);
    $("#ci").html(current_index);
    //alert(uli.index(start))
    var pic = uli.index(start);
        if(start.parent().is('#this')){
            start.unwrap();
        }else if(current_index == pic){
           start.wrap("<div id='this'></div>");
        }
}


$('#next').click(function(){
    current_index += 1;
    if(current_index > uli.length - 1){
     current_index = 0;   
    }
    cycle();
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    current_index -= 1;
    if(current_index < 0){
     current_index = uli.length -1;   
    }
    cycle();
});
```

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELRM/mq3ff740/)

I hope I have explained myself and thanks for your time I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the inner contents of the `li` and unwrap the contents of `#this`

```
function cycle() {
    $("#ci").html(current_index);
    $('#this').contents().unwrap();
    uli.eq(current_index).wrapInner('<div id="this"></div>');
}
```

```js
var current_index = -1;
var uli = $("#list li");

function cycle() {
  $("#ci").html(current_index);
  $('#this').contents().unwrap();
  uli.eq(current_index).wrapInner('<div id="this"></div>');
}


$('#next').click(function() {
  current_index++;
  if (current_index > uli.length - 1) {
    current_index = 0;
  }
  cycle();
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
  current_index--;
  if (current_index < 0) {
    current_index = uli.length - 1;
  }
  cycle();
});
```

```css
#this {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <!-- should be outside of the ul as span can't be a direct child of ul -->
  <span id='next'>Next</span>
  <ul id='list'>
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>Dog</li>
    <li>Eagle</li>
    <li>Fox</li>
    <li>Mouse</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- should be outside of the ul as span/div can't be a direct child of ul -->
  <span id='prev'>Prev</span>
  <div id='ci'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code:

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    current_index -= 1;
    if(current_index < 0){
     current_index = uli.length -1;   
    }
    // delete all other highlighted
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    // make this highlighted
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    cycle();
});
```

and in css for example:

```
  .highlight {
   border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well! I really appreciate it!